# Is there any way to break preposition at the end of a line to the next line in HTML

Tags: html, css

For example, I have this sentence:

```
foo bar bar foo bar foo a
lel lal foo bar
'a' should be placed before 'lel'
not at the end of the first line
```

So  'a' (and any other single symbol) should not remain at the end of a line when there isn't enough space for another full word to appear, but instead, be wrapped to the next line. Is there any way to achieve that with HTML and/or CSS?

Comment: Not with CSS. You need javascript

Comment: ... put a `<br>` before the "a"? If you mean an automated way, no. Otherwise HTML/CSS would have to know language rules, and it's supposed to be language neutral.